# Why do black-box deep learning algorithms produce better word similarities than cognitively plausible ones?

Tags: algorithms

Why do black-box deep learning algorithms (e.g. Mikolov et al 2013) produce better word similarities than cognitively plausible ones (e.g. Baayen et al 2011)? Could we combine the best of both worlds, biologically motivated learning mechanisms and state-of-the-art performance?

Comment: AI is now outperforming humans on various tasks without any strong consideration of biological plausibility... the human brain is not necessarily optimized or optimal for various purposes eg even familiar/ anthropocentric areas like language etc... however a bit more bkg would be helpful: why would one expect "cognitively plausible" models to be superior etc? ps a good topic for [chat]

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is that we don't know *why* current ML algorithms work well on a particular dataset, or *why* other ML algorithms don't.

Most researchers focus on finding ML algorithms that achieve high accuracy, regardless of how they achieve it.  Cognitive plausibility typically isn't a goal.

Generally, across much of computer science, our best methods often differ from how the brain works.  This is true for machine learning, for computer vision, for playing games like chess, and other tasks.  That could be viewed as an opportunity for improvement and a failure of our methods, or as an indication that the methods that will work best for computers might be different from the ones that our brains have evolved.  We just don't know.

Comment: there is a somewhat circular effect here. an algorithm "works best" when it is a "superior model" for the data. further analysis can verge on the philosophical. a simple answer: (wrt success of deep networks in particular but maybe explaining ML success in general) yan lecun lately says ["the world is compositional"](http://www.ibtimes.com/facebook-artificial-intelligence-companys-ai-chief-explains-how-he-tags-your-photos-1859128). (may try to work this into answer sometime)